# Steps in Migrating to Australia or New Zealand

Tags: skilled-migration

Can someone correct me in the steps that I need to embark upon if decide to migrate from Sri Lanka to Australia or New Zealand.

Can someone verify whether the order of steps below are correct or add up anything I have missed?

1. Skill Assessment
2. IELTS
3. Apply for Visa

Comment: You might also need to have your education assessed if it wasn't at a AUS/NZ university.

Comment: **From where**??

Comment: @JanDoggen Sri Lanka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Australian system is point-based. For independent skilled immigration you have to get 65 points. You could get points from your age, English level (IELTS), education or degree, professional experience, partner skills and some additional rare requirements. The details are [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-independent-189/points-table).

Skills, education, degree for you and your partner have to be assessed by Australian authorities.

Then you may submit an application for immigration. Processing time is 6 months. Then you will ask for the visa.